# "how to fix "No module named 'core' in django"

Tags: django, django-views

ajax_pro1 URL Configuration

```
"""
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.

Comment: Did you put your core app in the INSTALLED_APPS on Django settings?

Comment: i am not put core app in the installed_apps on django@Daniel Roseman